# TikZ: Placing a coordinate or node at end of edge

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, edge

How can I place a node or coordinate at end of the edge?

I expected this syntax:

```
\draw (0,0) edge +(1,1) coordinate (x);
```

Because the same syntax with the `--` command, it works:

```
\draw (0,0) -- +(1,1) coordinate (x);
```

But this is the result when I expected it to be a red line between the edges. It seems like both `edge one` and `edge two` is at `(0,0)`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw (0,0)
            edge +(20:3cm) coordinate (edge one)
            edge +(110:3cm) coordinate (edge two);
        \draw[red] (edge one) -- (edge two);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I expected this outcome as when using `--`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw (0,0) -- +(20:3cm) coordinate (edge one)
              (0,0) -- +(110:3cm) coordinate (edge two);
        \draw[red] (edge one) -- (edge two);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are some limitations in how `edge`s are constructed and in most cases `--` is actually the correct operator that should be used instead of `edge`.

Comment: @HenriMenke is the real expert here, but the best way to think about it in my opinion is that `edge` does not move the current point of the path - it's really storing a path operation that will be executed *after* the current path is drawn. This is why you can change line/arrow styles in an edge with respect to the main path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As work around try the following:

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw (0,0)
            edge coordinate[pos=1,pin=1] (edge one) +( 20:3cm) 
            edge coordinate[pos=1,pin=2] (edge two) +(110:3cm) ;
        \draw[red] (edge one) -- (edge two);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I add `pin` to coordinates that their position are clear visible (you can remove them form `coordinate` options, i.e. write just `coordinate[pos=1] (edge one)` etc).